# Implementing multiple PCs in one work station

Tags: linux, windows, synergy, multiple-desktop

is there a way to use to multiple PCs as a single workstation?
My current setup is a laptop+dock+dual monitors running Win7pro, a Desktop running Vista Business (which has its own keyboard, monitor and mouse) and a linux box (which I access via remote desktop and putty).  I have used synergy in the past with buggy results.
Is there a way I can have direct access to all 3 PCs and still use one keyboard and mouse?

Comment: A KVM does what you want

Comment: As a software-solution, `synergy` comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

[Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) will effectively combine your Windows 7 Pro and Linux boxes into one workstation. Its software for sharing your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers on your desk. No need to buy a KVM and have a pile of extra cables since Synergy is just software that works over your existing network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a KVM is the only real solution, Synergy also works but requires a monitor for each machine. I use Mouse Without Borders from Microsoft, but it is only for Windows so your Linux box would not be able to access and again you would have to have a monitor for each machine. I think a KVM is your best solution to be honest, you can just hit a hot key like Scroll Lock twice quick and it will switch to your next machine.

Comment: Maybe try Mouse Without Borders on Linux using Wine?

Comment: That's a good idea, I have never tried that. I would be curious if it works!

Answer (score 0):

There are some standard network protocols for remote desktop and applications.

In Linux/Unix you usually use X which is capable of serving your local screen, keyboard and mouse not only to local applications, but also to remote applications. Together with ssh you are able to encrypt the X network traffic. If remote machines are configured with some xdm, kdm or gdm login manager which allows network connections you can also connect not only to single applications but entire login and desktops with Xnest.

In Windws you usually use the remote desktop which allows you to login and acces an entire desktop in a Window.

From Linux you are able to access Windows remote desktop with a program like rdesktop. From Windows you are able to access Linux X applications with an X server like Xming together with putty for ssh.

There are also other protocols like VNC which allows you to connect to remote computers.